# Can we use bootstrap responsive with HTML5 structure eg: <header> <nav> <article> <section>

Tags: html, html5boilerplate

Can we use bootstrap responsive with HTML5 structure tags eg:

```
<header> <nav> <article> <section>
```

Comment: what bootstrap has in place will be responsive...it is up to you to make whatever else responsive

Comment: find some ..

http://www.theawkwardduck.com/bootstrap/bootstrap.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use any of those tags with Bootstrap.  But David Nguyen is right, if you don't use built-in Twitter-Bootstrap tags, then you need to compensate if they aren't responsive the way that you want.